# MVC Enum DropDown - Dynamic load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Am trying to Bind Dropdown in MVC using Enum and it works great !! Here is  sample code

```
  //Enum Set up
    public enum Name
    {
    Name1,
    Name2,
    Name3
    }

    public enum Number
    {
    11,
    12,
    13
    }
    public Name nameDropDown { get; set; }

    public Number numberDropDown { get; set; }

    //Like this i have have 10 Enums

    //View
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.numberDropDown) or @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.nameDropDown)
```

Here is where i got struck !!I am going to load only one dropdown in my view based on the condition. I can have if else if and load the drop down based  on the condition. But as i  have large list it wont be that good.

Is there a alternative way i can decide which enum to bind in my view ? Like dynamically locating based on the condition. Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to achieve this. One way would be to create an extension method, something like:

```
public enum Name { Name1, Name2, Name3 }
public enum Number {  Number1, Number2, Number3 }

public class ViewModel
{
    public Name nameDropDown { get; set; }
    public Number numberDropDown { get; set; }

    // x number of other enum properties
}

public static class MyHtmlHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MyEnumDropDownListFor(this HtmlHelper html, string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyInfo = typeof(ViewModel).GetProperty(propertyName);
        if (propertyInfo == null) return null;

        var expParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ViewModel)); 
        var expProp = Expression.Property(expParam, propertyName);
        var expression = Expression.Lambda(expProp, expParam);

        var htmlStr = (MvcHtmlString) typeof(SelectExtensions)
            .GetMethods()
            .First(m => m.Name == "EnumDropDownListFor" && m.IsGenericMethod)
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(ViewModel), propertyInfo.PropertyType)
            .Invoke(null, new object[] { html, expression });

        return htmlStr;
    }
}
```

And your view could fetch the property name from the query string and based on that show the dropdown list:

```
@model ViewModel

@{
   var propertyName = Request["property"] ?? "numberDropDown";
}

@Html.MyEnumDropDownListFor(propertyName)
```